General expression optiization with sympy (or other tool)
I would like to have ability to define my own filed with rules and operations, then have sympy do its magic with these expressions.
For example, use the math operations available in glm such as vec3, dot etc.
So I can define the elements and transformation rules like addition, multiplication etc and have the expressions optimized by my constructs and not split vectors into components - like it is done with Point3D and such.
How would I do that?
Is there any documentation?
Recommendation to other tools that can solve this or extend sympy?
Thanks

Sounds interesting, but it's not clear what you are trying to do; some examples would help others help you. Since it's more of an open-ended question, maybe a Sympy-specific forum is more appropriate (I don't know what that might be, maybe a web search will find one).

A simple example would be geometry. Currently there is a Point3 class but everything is calculated as components instead of actual points.
It would help a lot if If I could define basic operations like dot,cross etc all with relevant algebraic rules, and optimize/solve on that level.

Okay, it sounds like at this point the problem is pretty wide open still. My advice is to ask about geometry operations in a Sympy-specific forum, and probably it would help a lot if you would be more concrete about the problem you need to solve, or at least a specific example. I think Sympy can probably handle it, but I don't know any specifics.

Also, Maxima can do a lot of stuff in that respect, but Maxima is somewhat incoherent in the realm of vectors algebra; it is certainly possible, and several efforts have been made to build libraries, but there are a lot of idiosyncrasies. But if you want to use Maxima, I can help you with that.
